# I am using a Html form with PHP, how do i use $_GET to be assigned to a variable to be used in an IF statement in this specific code

Tags: php, html

This is my html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello and welcome to my site</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>are these 2 numbers equal? type yes or no in the box</p>

<p2>one</p2> and  eight

<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Answer: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my new php page containing a previous answer and im having new errors

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
var_dump($_GET['name']);
$answer = $_GET['name'];
$saying = "congratulations";
if ($answer == "yes"){

echo  $saying;
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

the new errors are referring to my php page which is welcome_get.php

Comment: <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    var_dump($_GET['name']);
    $answer = $_GET['name'];
  

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>

Answer (score 3):

```
var_dump($_GET['name']);
```

Additionally, to see all available GET params:

```
var_dump($_GET)
```

To assign to a new variable:

```
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){

    $answer = $_GET['name'];

    if($answer == 'something'){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i put $answer = $_GET['name']; would that be in my html file or a php file in dreamweaver

Comment: @webdevelopert you can't put php code in HTML file. So you have to do it in php file i.e. welcome_get.php.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<?php
  var_dump($_GET['name']);
  $answer = $_GET['name'];
  
?>


</body>
</html>

Comment: the above comment is what i put in my welcome_get.php file but its coming up with errors?

Comment: undefined index on both of these lines.
var_dump($_GET['name']);
$answer = $_GET['name'];

Comment: You can only assign the $_GET['name'] *after* you've submitted the form. Before you submit the form $_GET['name'] will be empty

Comment: how do i assign the $_GET ['name'] for after the form has been submitted? @GreensterRox

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a check on the variable, if your php file is both rendering the HTML and handling the form request then you should check for the variable before you use it. This will prevent undefined index errors

Answer (score 1):

You can use isset function to check if $_GET['var'] is set

```
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){
      $answer = $_GET['name'];
      $saying = "congratulations";
      if ($answer == "yes"){
       echo  $saying;
      }
    }
```